# How to create a product id for in app purchases

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I am trying to test in app purchases for my iPhone App and I see how to setup test users, but I am not sure how to create a product id that I can use.  I do not want to submit my app to the app store without testing, but it seems like you have to submit in order to manage in app purchase? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Does your bindle id contain a wildcard? You must create a new app in iTunesConnect but the bundle id cannot contain an *. it must be "com.yourcompanyname.yourappid". The reason is that the product id for in app purchase must be tied to a specific app bundle id and not a generic one.

Comment: No it does not have a wildcard, but I am wondering when I upload the binary it would automatically go into the In Review state, but I am not ready for it to be In Review. If I reject the binary, will it then make the products as invalid?

Comment: What has worked for me and I believe you need to do is uplaod the binary. It then goes into "Waiting for Review". It will be in Waiting for Review for days. That allows you to then reject the binary. Since there is no input field for the bundle id, I think this is how Apple gets the bundle id. I have a rejected binary and was able to add in app purchase items. My testing has worked. I do not have an approved app but I am successfully testing 3 in app purchase products. I had the same question. Apple should make this clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead and create your in-app purchase with your product Id of choice, just don't upload a screen grab (used strangely only for the review process) and it will all work.

You will need to create a new application and submit a build, but you can reject it straight away - in app purchasing needs to know the bundle id of your app otherwise it would not be able to create the required relationship.

Comment: The problem is that is seems on itunes connect that I can only create productIds for apps that have already been submitted. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I uploaded an app to itunes connect but have not submitted it for review yet, and I can click on "Manage In-App Purchases" but then it says I need a bundle id.

Comment: Roger, try submiting it for review and then reject then reject the binary which will return it to "Waiting for Review"