# itunes connect how to delete product which is in waiting for review status

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, itunes

i had create an app on itunes connect with in app purchase, there i make a mistake of creating generic product ids, where as the product id should be tied with the bundle id of your app, i came to know this thing by reading that post

[How to create a product id for in app purchases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756738/how-to-create-a-product-id-for-in-app-purchases)

i know that i can't edit the product id. so i am trying to delete the products one by one and then want to create new ones, but there is no button to delete the products, my app is in developer rejected status and my products are in waiting for review status, pleas guide me, how to do this. Regards Saad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, Here are steps to how to do it.

1. Develoepr.apple.com
2. Sign in
3. Itunes Connect
4. Sign in
5. Click Manage Your Applications
6. Select the app and Click on it
7. Click on View Details
8. Click on Binary Details
9. Click on reject this Binary

Hope this will help you.

Comment: You can go straight to itunesconnect.apple.com you know :)

Comment: :) yap Saad, you can start from step 3 if u want :D .. and thanks Luke for mention it